# Android Back Arrow Animation throughout entire Application

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have successfully achieved the Drawer Hamburger/ Arrow Spin Navigation in Home Activity.

It is working fine but **is limited to that specific activity**.

When I start an intent to **Activity B** I am unable to do the same spin animation.

Can I use it in my entire app, Just like Google Play. And how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a base activity and extend all other activities from it.
2. In base activity you need to override setcontentview(View view) method.
3. You can have your working Drawer Hamburger code of Activity A in base activity.
4. You should have a container view inside your layout of base activity.
5. Lets say Activity A extends BaseActivity
   so in oncreate of Activity A you will do setContentView (childview);
   Now this will give call to overrided method of BaseActivity. 
   Lets say BaseActivity has layout abc.xml with containerview.
6. Add this view to the container. Inflate from abc.xml and put it in view.
7. From view do containerview = view.findViewById(R.id.container).
8. Lets say container is linear layout. Now you do containerview.addView(child)
9. Give call to super.setcontentview(view);
10. Now for each and every activity you need to just extend from base activity and do setcontentview on it.

This is it. You can have a common layout structure throughout apps.